# System.Nanotime granularity and latency?

Tags: java, jmh

I am looking on to this `jmh` test http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/57623b7f64e6/jmh-core-benchmarks/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/benchmarks/NanoTimerBench.java, 
for the the `System.nanotime()`. 
But I don't really understand the difference between the measurement of granularity and latency. What is the difference between measuring latency and measuring granularity?

Comment: latency = delay, granularity = how big are the smallest parts i.e. grains.

Comment: [Nanotrusting the Nanotime](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/) by JMH guru Aleksey Shipilёv is also a good read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Granularity* is the resolution of the timer, e.g., how much time has to pass before you get back a different value. (As [Peter Lawrey put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599217/system-nanotime-granularity-and-latency#comment49267367_30599217), how big are the smallest pieces, e.g., "grains," it can measure.)

*Latency*, in this case, is basically how much time it takes to get the timer value.

So if it takes 10ns to get the timer value, but the timer values are only accurate to 100ns, then the *latency* is 10ns but the *granularity* is 100ns. With such a timer, you might call it two or three times in the course of, say, 40ns, and always get back the same "nanoseconds" value (because the granularity is larger than the latency).

Or you may have a system where it takes 20ns to get the timer value, but the value is accurate to 5ns. In that case, every call will give you a different value, because the granularity is smaller than the latency.

Comment: what about the timer should be monotonic ? I don't understand that.

Comment: @Bionix1441: See [Monotonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). Basically, in this case, it means that if you call `nanotime` twice, the value you got the first time must never be higher than the value you get the second time. The value should only ever *increase* (or, I believe, remain the same). So given `n1 = System.nanotime(); n2 = System.nanotime();`, `n2 - n1` must never be negative, only 0 or positive.

Comment: Does the monotony of nanotime have any impacts on granularity ? And also in the case you have latency and granularity the same value, is that possible ?

Comment: @Bionix1441: I don't know.